# Polygon Diameter

Tags: performance-tuning, geometry, algorithm, maximum, polygons

I want to calculate the diameter of a convex polygon. That is, the largest distance between any pair of vertices. Here's my approach

```
pol = Polygon@{{-6.4, -8.3}, {-5.5, -9}, {-5, -8.4}, {-5, -7.9}, {-5.9, -7.6}};
vts = pol[[1]];
AbsoluteTiming@
 Max@Table[Table[EuclideanDistance[vts[[i]], vts[[j]]],
  {j, i + 1, Length@vts}], {i, Length@vts - 1}]

(* {0.000058, 1.45602} *)
```

What do you think? Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

pol = Polygon@{{-6.4, -8.3}, {-5.5, -9}, {-5, -8.4}, {-5, -7.9}, \
{-5.9, -7.6}};

vts = pol[[1]];

AbsoluteTiming@Max[EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[vts, {2}]]

(* {0.000044, 1.45602} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! It didn't occur to me to use `Subsets`. I'm running the same version on Windows 10 and I compared both approaches (essentially listed the timings over 10^5 runs and took the mean). Just in case you're curious: my absolute timing converged to $0.000020782$, while yours to $0.0000125165$.

Comment: See [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html)

Answer (score 5):

See also `DistanceMatrix` which is a little slower than `Subsets`, and `Outer` which is about the same with this many points:

```
RepeatedTiming@Max@DistanceMatrix@pol[[1]]

RepeatedTiming[
 Max@Outer[EuclideanDistance, #, #, 1] &@pol[[1]]
 ]
```